# Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS behind load balancer

Tags: redirect, asp.net-core, https, .net-core

I'm moving an ASP.NET Core application to AWS Beanstalk and I'm having an issue forcing HTTPS for all requests.  The useful error from the logs is:

> Failed to determine the https port for redirect.

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) on enforcing HTTPS:

> If requests are forwarded in a reverse proxy configuration, use Forwarded Headers Middleware before calling HTTPS Redirection Middleware. Forwarded Headers Middleware updates the Request.Scheme, using the X-Forwarded-Proto header

Based on my setup it looks like it should be correct:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
    // aws ssl termination
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions() {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
    });

    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    } else {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/500");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    // lots of other stuff removed for brevity
}
```

The load balancer is accepting requests on HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443) and the application is setup in IIS to only accept requests on HTTP (80).  This and the error message makes it seem related to an [announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/301) they made, but based on the docs I would expect the forward headers middleware to resolve the issue.

**Update**

If instead of using `UseHttpsRedirection` I switch to using the `RequireHttpsAttribute` and `AddRedirectToHttps` rewrite middleware the redirects work correctly.  It's just the `UseHttpsRedirection` middleware that I can't get working.

Comment: Does AWS use different Forward head names? If so you have to configure the forward-header key names in the `UseForwardHeaders()` overload which has an options delegate

Comment: Nope, they don't.  If I switch to using the `RequireHttpsAttribute` and `AddRedirectToHttps` rewrite middleware the redirects work correctly.  It's just the `UseHttpsRedirection` that I can't seem to get working.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#port-configuration) the error comes when no port is configured. But since your reverse proxy is the termination endpoint, you can safely remove the `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`. Middleware such as authorization) will still recognize it as secure connection, when the headers and forwarded headers middleware are there. Or configure the port and don't expose it (in case you are using docker), then you can also test ssl locally

Comment: @Tseng In those docs they state:  `Apps deployed in a reverse proxy configuration allow the proxy to handle connection security (HTTPS). If the proxy also handles HTTPS redirection, there's no need to use HTTPS Redirection Middleware.`  My load balancer isn't performing the HTTPS redirection, so that's why I think I need the middleware.  Unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Okay me summarize: You send an HTTP request to the proxy, which is redirected to your application and then you get that error? Is that correct? HTTPs requests (to the proxy) on the proxy should then work, yes? In this case, you have to configure https on the application too (its required for the middleware, but it will only be invoked if the request didnt came from HTTPS, and no forwarded headers) . It can be a self-signed certificate, in a reverse proxy configuration it the 443 on the ASP.NET Core app should never be hit. Either that or do http->https redirection on the reverse proxy

Comment: Thanks @Tseng I think you cleared this up.  It sounds like in order to use the `UseHttpsRedirection` middleware my application **is required** to accept HTTPS requests *regardless* of the proxy sitting in front of it.  So even though the HTTPS requests at the app level would never be used it's still required.  I'm going to skip using the middleware since that's the requirement.  Setting it up at the app level will require extra scripts & step in our deploy process that don't really serve a purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Okay me summarize the comments:

> My load balancer isn't performing the HTTPS redirection, so that's why I think I need the middleware. Unless I'm misunderstanding?

So you send an HTTP request to the proxy, which is redirected to your application and then you get that error?

This is because the `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers have the value `http` and the Https Redirection middleware won't recognize it as secure protocol and try to redirect.

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#port-configuration), https configuration is required for the `UseHttpsRedirection`:

> A port must be available for the middleware to redirect an insecure request to HTTPS. If no port is available:
>
> - Redirection to HTTPS doesn't occur.
> - The middleware logs the warning "Failed to determine the https port for redirect."

HTTPS requests (to the proxy) on the proxy should then work, since the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header are set to `https` and the redirection Middleware should skip it.

In this case, you have to configure https on the application too (since its required for the middleware). It can be a self-signed certificate, in a reverse proxy configuration it the 443 on the ASP.NET Core app should never be hit. You don't even have to expose the port (when using Docker).

Alternatively, handle the https redirection on the reverse proxy itself. This is the better approach, as the requests will never hit your application in the first place unless its https.